# Putting Same Rank within Similar Values

Tags: oracle

I've a data in this format.

```
    ID Group    Flag
    1    A        Y
    2    A        Y
    3    A        Y
    4    A        Y
    5    A        N
    6    A        N
    7    A        N
    8    B        N
    9    B        Y
   10    B        Y
   11    B        Y
   12    B        N
   13    B        N
   14    B        N
```

I want to get the ranking of the variables in the following order.

```
  ID Group      Flag    Rank
  1    A         Y       1
  2    A         Y       1
  3    A         Y       1
  4    A         Y       1
  5    A         N       0
  6    A         N       0
  7    A         N       0
  8    B         N       0
  9    B         Y       2
 10    B         Y       2
 11    B         Y       2
 12    B         N       0
 13    B         Y       3
 14    B         Y       3
```

Can anyone please tell me how to get this result?

**summary of why particular order in above result:**
 I want to take max of the values for each group where Flag = "Y". The values will be selected only if they are coming continuously. For example, in case of B, I'll get 2 max values instead of 1. So, the idea is to differentiate the flags within each group

**Test data:**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST
(
GROUPP VARCHAR(2),
fLAG VARCHAR(2)
)

INSERT INTO #TEST
SELECT    'A',       'Y' UNION ALL
SELECT    'A',       'Y' UNION ALL
SELECT    'A',       'Y' UNION ALL
SELECT    'A',       'Y' UNION ALL
SELECT    'A',       'N' UNION ALL
SELECT    'A',       'N' UNION ALL
SELECT    'A',       'N' UNION ALL
SELECT    'B',       'N' UNION ALL
SELECT    'B',       'Y' UNION ALL
SELECT    'B',       'Y' UNION ALL
SELECT    'B',       'Y' UNION ALL
SELECT    'B',       'N' UNION ALL
SELECT    'B',       'N' UNION ALL
SELECT    'B',       'N'
```

Comment: How are you ordering these results?  Unless you have some kind of `ID` column that you can order by, there is no guarantee that the order you get will be the same.  SQL represents *unordered* sets of data.

Comment: Without something to order on, you're going to have a problem with   `B      Y       3`

Comment: Unable to establish a pattern in the result. Can you add some description to the output?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added the ID column in the data.

Comment: could you explain about your expected output particulary why you want B column in that order ?

Comment: I don't understand the final two rows.

Comment: @TheGameiswar: I want to take max of the values for each group where Flag = "Y". The values will be selected only if they are coming continuously. For example, in case of B, I'll get 2 max values instead of 1. So, the idea is to differentiate the flags within each group. Hope I could clear myself. Thanks!

Comment: @Jayvee: Are you asking, which database I'm using..it's Oracle. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's Oracle and not something else, such as MySQL? Those create table/insert statements do not look like valid Oracle syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started. 
But I just realized you want rank determined in another way than I first thought.

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    ID int not null, 
    [group] char not null, 
    flag char not null
)

INSERT INTO #test
SELECT 1, 'A', 'Y'
UNION
SELECT 2, 'A', 'Y'
UNION
SELECT 3, 'A', 'Y'
UNION
SELECT 4, 'A', 'Y'
UNION
SELECT 5, 'A', 'N'
UNION
SELECT 6, 'A', 'N'
UNION
SELECT 7, 'A', 'N'
UNION
SELECT 8, 'B', 'N'
UNION
SELECT 9, 'B', 'Y'
UNION
SELECT 10, 'B', 'Y'
UNION
SELECT 11, 'B', 'Y'
UNION
SELECT 12, 'B', 'N'
UNION
SELECT 13, 'B', 'N'
UNION
SELECT 14, 'B', 'N'


select *
from #test

SELECT
     ID,
     [Group],
     Flag,
     CASE 
          WHEN Flag = 'N' THEN 0
     ELSE
          ASCII([Group])-ASCII('A')+1
     END Rank
FROM
     #test
ORDER BY
     ID
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

This is a MySQL response...

I don't really understand what you're after, but here's something with which to experiment...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,my_group    CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,flag CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
( 1,'A','Y'),
( 2,'A','Y'),
( 3,'A','Y'),
( 4,'A','Y'),
( 5,'A','N'),
( 6,'A','N'),
( 7,'A','N'),
( 8,'B','N'),
( 9,'B','Y'),
(10,'B','Y'),
(11,'B','Y'),
(12,'B','N'),
(13,'B','Y'),
(14,'B','Y');

SELECT id
     , my_group
     , flag
     , CASE WHEN flag = 'N' THEN 0 ELSE CEILING(i/2) END rank
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN flag <> @prev THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=@i END + 1 i
            , @prev:=flag
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @i:=0,@prev:=null) vars
        ORDER
           BY id
     ) a;

+----+----------+------+------+
| id | my_group | flag | rank |
+----+----------+------+------+
|  1 | A        | Y    |    1 |
|  2 | A        | Y    |    1 |
|  3 | A        | Y    |    1 |
|  4 | A        | Y    |    1 |
|  5 | A        | N    |    0 |
|  6 | A        | N    |    0 |
|  7 | A        | N    |    0 |
|  8 | B        | N    |    0 |
|  9 | B        | Y    |    2 |
| 10 | B        | Y    |    2 |
| 11 | B        | Y    |    2 |
| 12 | B        | N    |    0 |
| 13 | B        | Y    |    3 |
| 14 | B        | Y    |    3 |
+----+----------+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I marked Jonny's answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you could do it in Oracle, using [Tabibitosan](http://rwijk.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/tabibitosan.html):

```
with test as (select 1 id, 'A' groupp,'Y' flag from dual union all
              select 2, 'A', 'Y' from dual union all
              select 3, 'A', 'Y' from dual union all
              select 4, 'A', 'Y' from dual union all
              select 5, 'A', 'N' from dual union all
              select 6, 'A', 'N' from dual union all
              select 7, 'A', 'N' from dual union all
              select 8, 'B', 'N' from dual union all
              select 9, 'B', 'Y' from dual union all
              select 10, 'B', 'Y' from dual union all
              select 11, 'B', 'Y' from dual union all
              select 12, 'B', 'N' from dual union all
              select 13, 'B', 'Y' from dual union all
              select 14, 'B', 'Y' from dual)

select id,
       groupp,
       flag,
       grp,
       grp_id,
       case when flag = 'Y' then
                 dense_rank() over (partition by flag order by grp_id)
            else 0
       end rnk
from   (select id,
               groupp,
               flag,
               grp,
               min(case when flag = 'Y' then id end) over (partition by groupp, grp, flag) grp_id
        from   (select id,
                       groupp,
                       flag,
                       row_number() over (partition by groupp order by id)
                         - row_number() over (partition by groupp, flag order by id) grp
                from   test))
order by id;
```

First, we identify each set of consecutive flags by finding the difference of the row number for each value of the groupp column in id order and the row_number of the groupp and flag values in id order. Where there are gaps, the difference will jump - this is tabibitosan.

Once you've identified the groups, it's then a matter of assigning the rank numbers. Since we're assigning the ranks over the entire flag (ie. *not* partitioning by each groupp value), we need to work out how to order the ranking. To do this, I've simply found the lowest id per each (groupp, flag, grp).

Then we can assign the rank accordingly, making sure to set the 'N' flag rows to 0.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer! It was a beauty and exactly fulfill my requirement. And you also very clearly explain the answer. I already marked Johnny answer as correct. But I'll up vote some of your other answers. Thanks a lot!